# Runner.run parameter not available

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In the documentation it's said that it's possible to use options to configure the runner.
I would like to use the disableMultipleWindows option

```
runner.run({ disableMultipleWindows: true });
```

But I get the message :

```
Argument of type '{ disableMultipleWindows: boolean; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<RunOptions>'
```

Is this a bug or is this option deliberately not activated yet?

I am using the latest stable release v1.14.2

Answer (score 1):

`disableMultipleWindows` works, but there are some issues when using it in TypeScript. We are working on this issue. You can follow our progress here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6315.

There is also a [workaround](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6315#issuecomment-864835640).